# How does one deploy multiple micro-services in Node on a single AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

We are pretty new to AWS and looking to deploy multiple services into one EC2 instance.

- Each micro-service is developed in its own repository.
- Each service will have its own endpoint URL
- Services may talk to each other
- Services can be updated/deployed separately

Do we need a beanstalk for each? I hope not.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way we tackled a similar issue at our workplace was to leverage the [multi-container docker platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) supported by Elastic Beanstalk in most AWS regions.

The way this works in brief is, we had dedicated repositories for each of our services in ECR (Elastic Container Registry) where the different "versioned" images were deployed using a deploy script.

Once that is configured and set up, all you would need is deploy a  [`Dockerrun.aws.json`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun) file which basically highlights all the apps you would want to deploy as part of the docker cluster into 1 EC2 instance (make sure it is big enough to handle multiple applications). This is the file where one would also highlight `link` between applications (so they can talk to one another), port configurations, logging drivers and groups (yea we used AWS CloudWatch for logging) and many other fields. This JSON is very similar to one's `docker-compose.yml` which is used to bring up your stack for local development and testing.

I would suggest checking out the sample example configuration that Amazon provides for more information. Also, I found the [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/) documentation to be pretty helpful in this regard.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, one of our top engineers already implemented the docker pattern and it seems that it's inline with your recommendation!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you have a particular tool in mind. If you are using any tool for deployment of a single micro-service, multiple should be the same.

> How does one deploy multiple micro-services in Node on a single AWS
>   EC2 instance?
>
> Each micro-service is developed in its own repository.
>
> Services can be updated/deployed separately

This should be the same as deployment of a single micro-service. As long as they have different path and port that they are running on, it should be fine.

> Each service will have its own endpoint URL

You can use `nginx` as a reverse proxy which can redirect your request from port 80 to the required port of your micro service.

> Services may talk to each other

This again should not be an issue. You can either call them directly with the port number or via fully qualified name and come back via nginx.